# Fineuploader 4 (using s3): Is it possible to select a file using the dropbox chooser?

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-s3, dropbox-api, fine-uploader

Fine uploader provides the functionality needed to upload files directly to S3, rather than passing them through EC2, but my previous set up allowed the user to select a file either form their hard drive or from dropbox using the chooser (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js). This was simple as I could just check in PHP which input field was not empty.

Is there a way to achieve the same functionality but using fineuploader to process the file that's selected via the dropbox chooser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting a file via the dropbox chooser will result in a URL to that file.  Fine Uploader expects an actual file to be sent with each request at this time.  If you'd like integration with that dropbox chooser API or the ability to send URLs in place of actual files, you will need to [open up a feature request in the Github project's issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/new).

Comment: That's great, thank you for your help. I will open a new question about using the s3 php class (http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/) to upload direct to S3 from dropbox.